# Motion tracker fails when parenting a frozen picture on adobe after effects CC 2018

Tags: adobe, motion, after-effects

I followed a lot of tutorial and I think I missing something completely but I can't figure it out what... It drives me crazy.

I've a video in which I would like to paint a small part of a wall.

- I start by duplicating my layer with my video. With the clone stamp tool, I « paint » my wall;
- Then I freeze the picture.
- I create then a null object, I rename it to Tracker
- I select the back layer (not the duplicated one I turned to a frozen picture)
- I put a motion tracker on it (rotation checked). I define the null object as a target and when I analyze it, the tracker follow well the spot I’ve chosen. I apply it then.
- I do the parenting stuff

But this time, my frozen picture is, at first, no where to be seen and then on another, completely different spot…

I tried it a dozen of time, every way I can think of but it never work... Can somebody tell me what I'm missing ?

Any help would be really appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I receive the answer to my problems (there were a few of them) on the adobe AE forum: https://forums.adobe.com/message/10669912#10669912